# Formulaically Locating a Block of Cells From a Search Result

Tags: excel

I have a table of data which lists a series of dates against a list of members regarding attendance. I want to find the attendance for each member against a subset of dates. For example:

```
     A          B            C            D           E            F
1           2015/02/15   2015/02/10   2015/02/5   2015/01/26   2015/01/16
2  Person1       x            y            y           y            y
3  Person2       x            x            x           x            x
4  Person3       y            x            x           y            x
```

If I have a date, for example, `2015/02/12` in cell `B12` then I want to be able to find the closest date prior to it (which in the table would be `C1`; `2015/02/10`) and then select the values in the cells `C2:F2` (i.e. the cell and the three 'behind' it). From the values in these cells, I would then like to determine whether or not they have attended at least twice out of the four occasions (in this example, Person1 has, Person2 and Person3 haven't).

I have found a formula to get the closest date `=MAX(($B$1:$F$1<=B12)*B1:F1)` however I don't know how to use this to get the cell location and to then 'expand' that to get the member's data.

I require this to be done in a formula as I can't use scripts or macros. I can, if necessary, use additional cells for 'intermediate' data.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your closest date is in C12, please try in J2 and copied down:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(C$12,A$1:F$1,0),3)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(C$12,A$1:F$1,0)+3,3)),"y")>1
```